# Cuda, executional thread order in a 3d-block

Tags: cuda

As title, I would like to know the right execution order in case we have a 3d block

I think to remember that I read already something regarding it, but it was some time ago, I dont remember where but it was coming by someone who didnt look so reliable..

Anyway I would like to have some confirmations about it.

Is it as the following (divided in warps)?

[0, 0, 0]...[blockDim.x, 0, 0] - [0, 1, 0]...[blockDim.x, 1, 0] - (...) - [0, blockDim.y, 0]...[blockDim.x, blockDim.y, 0] - [0, 0, 1]...[blockDim.x, 0, 1] - (...) - [0, blockDim.y, 1]...[blockDim.x, blockDim.y, 1] - (...) - [blockDim.x, blockDim.y, blockDim.z]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct ordering; threads are ordered with the x dimension varying first, then y, then z (equivalent to column-major order) within a block. The calculation can be expressed as

```
int threadID = threadIdx.x + 
               blockDim.x * threadIdx.y + 
               (blockDim.x * blockDim.y) * threadIdx.z;

int warpID = threadID / warpSize;
int laneID = threadID % warpsize;
```

Here `threadID` is the thread number within the block, `warpID` is the warp within the block and `laneID` is the thread number within the warp.

Note that threads are not necessarily executed in any sort of predicable order related to this ordering within a block. The execution model guarantees that *threads in the same warp* are executed "lock-step", but you can't infer any more than that from the thread numbering within a block.

Comment: No. This ordering is not guaranteed.