# How would you calculate warpid across all possible block dimensions?

Tags: cuda

```
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x;
unsigned int warpid = tid / warpSize;
```

This is good for blocks with more than one dimension right?

```
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int j = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int k = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    int tid = i + j + k;

    int l = tid / warpSize;
```

Is that right? I know this doesn't make sense...

Comment: What is the definition of warp id? What should `tid` physically represent?

Comment: `int tid = i * j * k;` does not generate unique identifier. For example, 2 = 2 * 1 * 1 = 1 * 2 * 1.

Comment: @JackOLantern understands this is a CUDA question. And his question is a very pertinent one. Are you wanting to calculate a unique thread index and warp index at the scope of a block or something else? Your edited code is total nonsense, BTW.

Comment: You have shown three very different pieces of code since you first asked this question, but haven't yet answered the very first comment which goes to the complete core of your problem, which seems to not be related to warp IDs at all, but thread numbering in multi-dimensionsal grids. This has been asked many times before here - like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11554280/681865) for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute thread id (block unique) and respect the way how the threads are organized on GPU :

`int tid = threadIdx.x + 
           threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + 
           threadIdx.z * blockDim.x * blockDim.y;`

To compute warp id: 
`int warpid = tid / 32;`

By this, threads with the same `warpid` belong to the same warp.

**EDIT:**

As it is stated above this computation of `tid` is only block unique. You can not use it to access unique index of the arrays `A, B, C`. Similarly, the variable `warpid` stores only block unique index of warp.

The reason why your approach works for one dimensional blocks and grid is that the expression `int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;` calculates grid unique thread id and variables `j` and `k` equal zero.

So, computation of identifiers depends on the purpose as well as on the dimensions of blocks and grid. For example, if you want to compute global identifiers of threads to access some global memory arrays with 1D grid and 3D blocks:

`int tid = threadIdx.x + 
           threadIdx.y * blockDim.x + 
           threadIdx.z * blockDim.x * blockDim.y +
           blockIdx.x * blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z; // number of threads in prior blocks`

and the calculation of the warp identifier depends on the purpose (whether you are interested in global or block unique id) as well.

Comment: For future-proofing, wouldn't it be better to use `warpSize` instead of the literal 32?