# CUDA Kernel not returning values

Tags: cuda, openmp, thrust

I am working with a server that has multiple GPUs. I am using openMP to launch a kernel over multiple GPUs at once. The problem I am seeing is that the Kernel I am running does not seem to update the values in the thrust device vectors it is passed. The code below should output a value of 1 for all elements in the device vectors but instead outputs a value of 0. The code compiles and runs and shows me that the kernel executes successfully.

I do not understand why this code is not behaving as expected.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_ptr.h>
#include <thrust/device_malloc.h>
#include <thrust/device_free.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>



using namespace::std;


const long N_R1 = 100;
const long N_R2 = 100;


__global__ void kernel(long* ND, long* NR1, 
                       float* a, float* b, float* c, float* d)

{
    // Calculate Global index (Generic 3D block, 3D thread)
    long idx = ( blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z )
              * ( threadIdx.z * ( blockDim.x*blockDim.y ) ) + threadIdx.y 
              * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    //Values correspond to 2D array limits
    long idxR1 = idx / ND[0];
    long idxR2 = idx % ND[0];

    if(idxR1 >= NR1[0] || idxR2 >= ND[0])
    {
        return;
    }

        a[idx] =1.0;
        b[idx] =1.0;
        c[idx] =1.0;
        d[idx] =1.0;

}


void kernel_wrapper()
{
    // GPU Count
    int num_gpus = 0;
    cudaGetDeviceCount(&num_gpus);
    omp_set_num_threads(num_gpus);

    //Calculate Dimensioning
    long D_total = N_R1 * N_R2;
    //Region 1 coordinates are loaded on to each GPU
    //Region 2 coordinates are divided up onto GPUs
    long R2_stride = ceil(float(N_R2)/float(num_gpus));

    //Distance arrays need to be split longo whole sections of region 1. 
    //(Distances size = N_R1 * N_R2) subset of distance size needs to be N_R1
    long D_stride = R2_stride * N_R1;


#pragma omp parallel
    {

        // Get CPU thread number
        long cpu_thread_id = omp_get_thread_num();

        cudaSetDevice(cpu_thread_id);

        // Set up Local Arrays for distance and potential
        // Step 1: Calculate rough Array Limits
        // If array spaces divide evenly between threads then beginnings and endings can be calculated below
        long R2_begin = cpu_thread_id * R2_stride;
        long D_begin  = cpu_thread_id * D_stride;

        long R2_end = R2_begin + R2_stride;
        long D_end  = D_begin + D_stride;

        // Step 2: Check Ends are not out of bounds
        //         The last thread in the calculation is likely to have array sizings that are out of bounds
        //         if this is the case then the ends need to be clipped:
        if(R2_end >= N_R2)
        {
            R2_end = N_R2;
        }
        if(D_end >= D_total)
        {
            D_end = D_total;
        }

        // Local aray sizes are (end - begin)
        long l_R2 = R2_end - R2_begin;
        long l_D     = D_end - D_begin;

        float zero = 0.0;
        // Create Region 2 potential components
        thrust::host_vector<float > a(l_D,zero);
        thrust::host_vector<float > b(l_D,zero);
        thrust::host_vector<float > c(l_D,zero);
        thrust::host_vector<float > d(l_D,zero);

        long* p_NR1;
        long nr1 = N_R1;
        cudaMalloc( (void**)&p_NR1, sizeof(long) );
        cudaMemcpy( p_NR1, &nr1, sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        long* p_NR2;
        cudaMalloc( (void**)&p_NR2, sizeof(long) );
        cudaMemcpy( p_NR2, &l_D, sizeof(long), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

        //Generate Device Side Data for region 2 potential components
        thrust::device_vector< float > d_a = a;
        thrust::device_vector< float > d_b = b;
        thrust::device_vector< float > d_c = c;
        thrust::device_vector< float > d_d = d;
        // Generate pointers to Device Side Data for region 2 potential components
        float* p_a = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_a.data());
        float* p_b = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_b.data());
        float* p_c = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_c.data());
        float* p_d = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(d_d.data());

        dim3 blocks = N_R1;
        dim3 threads = l_R2;
        kernel<<<blocks,threads>>>(p_NR2, p_NR1,
                                   p_a, p_b, p_c, p_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        if(cudaGetLastError() == cudaSuccess)
        {
            cout << "Kernel Successful!" << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << endl;
            cin.ignore(1);
        }

        a = d_a;
        b = d_b;
        c = d_c;
        d = d_d;

        for(long j = 0; j != a.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "a[" << j << "] = " << a[j] << endl;
        }
        for(long j = 0; j != b.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "b[" << j << "] = " << b[j] << endl;
        }
        for(long j = 0; j != c.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "c[" << j << "] = " << c[j] << endl;
        }
        for(long j = 0; j != c.size(); j++)
        {
            cout << "c[" << j << "] = " << c[j] << endl;
        }
}
        cin.ignore(1);
}

int main()
{

    kernel_wrapper();

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You probably want to copy the result back from the device to the host before checking it...

Comment: @tera I think for example `a=da;` (thrust) does that.  According to my testing, some of the `a` values (for example) are getting set to 1 and are being printed out as 1.  However not all, and that appears to be incorrect index calculations in the kernel.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I could have sworn these lines weren't there when I looked, but obviously the question has not been edited. I should probably refrain from shooting comments from the hip while working on something else.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the output values are getting set to 1, some are not.  The problem is due to this statement:

```
// Calculate Global index (Generic 3D block, 3D thread)
long idx = ( blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z )
          * ( threadIdx.z * ( blockDim.x*blockDim.y ) ) + threadIdx.y 
          * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

That isn't what I would call a proper generic conversion of 3D grid/block to globally unique 1D index, which I assume is your intent.  Let's just pick one example to prove that it is broken.  Suppose you are launching a 1D grid of 1D blocks (which is what you are doing).  Then all of the (block,thread)Idx.y and .z variables will all be zero.  Only blockIdx.x and threadIdx.x can take on non-zero values in that launch configuration.

In that case your expression reduces to:

```
// Calculate Global index (Generic 3D block, 3D thread)
long idx = ( blockIdx.x + 0 * gridDim.x * gridDim.y * 0 )
          * ( 0 * ( blockDim.x*blockDim.y ) ) + 0 
          * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
```

i.e. it reduces to:

```
long idx = threadIdx.x;
```

So the first (block-size) elements of your arrays (a,b,c,d) are getting set properly, the rest are not.  Since `threadIdx.x` is not unique from one block to the next, this is not a proper globally-unique thread ID, and therefore each block is writing the *same* output locations, rather than each taking care of a separate part of the array.

So what is a possible (correct) generic 3D-to-1D index conversion?

That is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11570329/1695960) (and probably other places).  This answer actually only converts a 3D grid plus 1D block configuration to a globally-unique ID, but it is sufficient for demonstration purposes of what is wrong in this code.

When I replace your in-kernel calculation of `idx` with that code, your kernel populates all array entries with 1.0 according to my testing.